# Column still shows a filter after clear using the DT package in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This issue occurs in both Google Chrome and Firefox, however it seems to be okay in Internet Explorer.  If I have a data table with a factor column and filters enabled,  I can select which factors in the column I want to filter on.  Then if I clear the filters by proxy, the table resets, but if I click in the filter input, it still shows that the filter is selected, even if it really isn't.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput("table"))),
  fluidRow(actionButton("clear", "Clear Filters"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- data.frame(LETTERS = c("A", "B", "C"))

  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(data, filter = list(position = "top", clear = FALSE))})

  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    clearSearch(proxy = dataTableProxy("table"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here the table is filtered on "A"

[image]

Then by clicking the "Clear Filters" button to clear the filters by proxy, the table unfilters and the filter on "A" appears to be gone.

[image]

However, clicking in the filter box shows "A" as still being a selected filter, even though it really isn't.

[image]

Is this something that could even be fixed within the DT package or is it an issue with Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by creating a function in javascript to clear the filter inputs on the client side to then be called after running the `clearSearch` function from DT.  For simplicity, I created a wrapper function called `clearColumnSearch` that does both.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

clearColumnSearch <- function(proxy) {
  clearSearch(proxy = proxy)
  proxy$session$sendCustomMessage(type = "clearColumnSearch", message = list(tableid = proxy$id))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(2, DTOutput("table"))),
  fluidRow(actionButton("clear", "Clear Filters")),
  tags$script(HTML("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('clearColumnSearch',
  function(x) {
    // outputId of the DT element
    var table = document.getElementById(x.tableid);
    // filter row of the table element within the DT element
    var tablerow = table.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].rows[1];
    // loop through each cell in the filter row
    for (var i = 0, cell; cell = tablerow.cells[i]; i++) {
      if(['factor', 'logical'].includes(cell.getAttribute('data-type'))) {
        // find the selectize object
        var dropdown = $(cell).find('.selectized').eq(0)[0].selectize;
        // set to blank
        dropdown.setValue('');
      } else if(['number', 'integer', 'date', 'time'].includes(cell.getAttribute('data-type'))) {
        // find the slider object
        var slider = $(cell).find('.noUi-target').eq(0);
        // get the endpoints of the slider
        var min = slider.noUiSlider('options')['range']['min'];
        var max = slider.noUiSlider('options')['range']['max'];
        // set the value of the slider
        slider.val([min, max]);
      } else {}
    }
});"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- data.frame(LETTERS = c("A", "B", "C"))

  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(data, filter = list(position = "top", clear = FALSE))})

  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    clearColumnSearch(proxy = dataTableProxy("table"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```